# Weird sound comming from speakers

Tags: sound, sd-card, ubuntu-drivers

Hi I have a HP stream 14 running Ubuntu off a micro SD card and I hear a buzzing noise out of the speakers, the laptop is fanless and had a ssd so it is not those that are making the noise. Do I need a driver update? Or can I just disable the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect AC-DC power supply from laptop. Sometimes 50-60Ghz noise transfers from electrical network through PSU to ear-buds or speakers.

Comment: Good call. I have experienced that an off-brand power cable can cause this.

Comment: I was looking for a more permanent fix but OK I will try that. I understand it may be un fixable

Comment: I had an HP laptop that did this. I had to use the OEM power cable to fix it.

Comment: @jbrock I am using the OEM charger this only happens in Ubuntu